# Generics in Kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, kotlin

I have a problem translating this java method call to kotlin:

```
doCallRealMethod().when(useCase).execute(any(Action1.class));
```

Kotlin equivalent (created with the kotlin plugin automatically):

```
doCallRealMethod().`when`(useCase).execute(ArgumentMatchers.any(Action1<*>::class.java!!))
```

useCase variable is defined like: UseCase<*>

The compile problem is on this part: Action1<*>::class.java

Compiler says:

```
"Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal"
```

So If I remove the <*> part, then this not compile either:

```
doCallRealMethod().`when`(useCase).execute(ArgumentMatchers.any(Action1::class.java!!))
```

Compiler says then:

```
Out-projected type 'UseCase<*>!' prohibits the use of 'public open fun execute(onNextAction: Action1<T!>!): Unit defined in com.ubox.app.main.domain.UseCase'
```

If I change UseCase<*> with UseCase<T>, then the compiler complains again with the part Action1::class.java!!, and says:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Action1<*>! but Action1<T!>! was expected
```

I'm completely stucked with this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827144/class-literal-syntax-for-parameterized-classes-in-kotlin has the answer to your question, I guess.

Comment: Yes, a casting with  as (Action1<T>) maded it, thanks you!