# only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal when using Mockito and kotlin

Tags: android, mockito, kotlin

I used Android studio's conversion tool to convert existing java test class.

I am getting this error :

> only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal

Here is the test case used :

Java

```
doAnswer(answerVoid(
            (OnDataListListener<List<BEntity>> myCallback) -> myCallback.onSuccess(mList))).when(
            mInteractor).performGetBList(any(OnDataListListener.class), anyBoolean());
```

Kotlin

```
doAnswer(answerVoid { listener: OnDataListListener<List<BEntity>> ->
      listener.onSuccess(
          emptyList())
    }).`when`<DragonInteractor>(mInteractor)
        .performGetBList(any<OnDataListListener>(OnDataListListener<*>::class.java),
            anyBoolean())
```

So how to use generic params in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just use [`OnDataListListener::class.java`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references).

The reason why the angle brackets are not required (and not allowed) in a class reference expresison is that class references are completely agnostic of generics, there are no different class references for generic specializations of a class.

Comment: how about the "any" in here :  any<*>(OnDataListListener::class.java) . I even have this one here but still is not compiling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32827711/2187976

Comment: @MohamedALOUANE, should it be just `any(OnDataListListener::class.java)`? If that does not compile, try `any<OnDataListListener<*>>(OnDataListListener::class.java)`

Answer (score 0):

first remove `OnDataListListener<*>::class.java` parameter
then add the `List<BEntity>` in `OnDataListListener` parameter types

the result is

```
doAnswer(answerVoid { listener: OnDataListListener<List<BEntity>> ->
  listener.onSuccess(
      emptyList())
}).`when`<DragonInteractor>(mInteractor)
    .performGetBList(any<OnDataListListener<List<BEntity>>>(),
        anyBoolean())
```